# Factorial of Infinite Cardinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have been thinking about the following problem:

> Let $A$ be a set of cardinality $k$ and denote $\sum_A$ the set of all bijection from $A$ to $A$.
>
> Also denote $k! = \mathrm{card}\left(\sum_A \right)$. Prove that $k!=2^k$.

My proof consists of finding a bijection $F:\sum_A\to P(A)$ which associates each bijection from the left to the set of its fixed points. Then the result would follow.
($P(A)$=the power set of $A$).

Since this proof seems quite easy I am afraid it is wrong. Can someone enlighten me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your $F$ isn’t a bijection: many different permutations can have the same set of fixed points.

Comment: F isn't a bijection. (This is obvious if you look at some explicit elements of $\Sigma_A$ when A has size, say, 3.)

Comment: Ok, now I see. But if I take $F:P(A)->\sum_A$ as before I would get an injective function so I have $2^k\leq K!$

Comment: @Cubic: There isn't such an $F$: if $x \in A$, then $A \setminus \{ x \}$ cannot be the set of fixed points of a permutation! That flat can be patched up, though. It is probably worth making a precise statement of what you are assuming to make your argument work. (and then prove the precise statement)

Comment: Notationally, I would write $\Sigma_A$ and not $\sum_A$.  That is, `\Sigma` not `\sum`.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, unless you limit yourself to infinite sets this statement is wrong. It is wrong because for $k=3$ we have $3!=6<8=2^3$.

For infinite sets, assuming the axiom of choice, this is true. To see why note that $f\colon A\to A$ means that $f\subseteq A\times A$, so $\Sigma_A\subseteq\mathcal P(A\times A)$.

Assuming the axiom of choice $|A|=|A\times A|$ and therefore $|\Sigma_A|\leq 2^k$. You still have to show the other direction holds as well. In order to show that, you need to find $2^k$ distinct bijections from $A$ to itself.

**Hint:** There are $2^k$ different pairs $A_1,A_2\subseteq A$ such that $\{A_1,A_2\}$ is a partition of $A$ and $|A_1|=|A_2|$. For every such pair we define a unique $f\colon A\to A$ which sends $A_1$ to $A_2$ and vice versa, conclude the wanted equality of cardinals.

Comment: Two questions: 1) To show there are $2^k$ different partitions of equal sizes, it is enough to show $\{B\subset A\;|\;|B| = |A\backslash B|\}\sim P(A)$. An injection is clear, but surjection I could not find. 2) To conclude that for each $A_1,A_2$ we have such a $f:A\to A$ with $A_1$ bijectively sent to $A_2$ and vice versa, are we using AC?

Comment: **Hint:** Partition $A$ into three parts of the same size as $A$, $A_1,A_2,A_3$. Then take any $B\subseteq A_1$ and consider $A_2\cup B$ and $A_3\cup(A_1\setminus B)$ as a partition. How many subsets of $A_1$ are there?

Comment: Also, we have to use the axiom of choice. Otherwise one can come up with counterexamples.

Comment: Your new hint is a great argument, never would thought about that!

Comment: How to argue that I can have $A_1\sqcup A_2 \sqcup A_3 = A$ all of same size as $A$? Are you using Dedekind infinite or just infinite?

Comment: @mezhang: You have to use Dedekind-infiniteness, sets which are Dedekind-finite have no such partitions. But you have to use *more* than that. You have to use the fact that the axiom of choice implies that $|A|=|A|+|A|$, and therefore $|A|+|A|+|A|$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- Every on $A$ bijection is a function from $A$ to $A$.
- Every function from $A$ to $A$ is a relation on $A\times A$.
- A relation on $A\times A$ is just a subset of $A\times A$.
- What's the cardinality of $A\times A$ when $A$ is infinite?

Comment: That's just one side of the deal. It shows that $|\Sigma_A|\leq2^k$.