# factorial of infinite Cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

> Let $S_A$ be set of all bijections over $A$ such that
>   $Card(A)=\kappa$. Define foctorial as $\kappa!:=Card(S_A)$. Show that if $\kappa$ is  infinite, then : $\kappa!=2^\kappa$

First, I've proved this definition is well-defined. Then I wanted to use **Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein**'s theorem to find injections between $S_A$ and $2^A$ or $\mathcal{P}A$, but I'm still searching for it. If it is possible, then there's no need to use **Axiom of Choice** and it is provable in **ZF**.

Actually, injection of desired functions must be proved directly from injection of $f\in S_A$. So my first attempt was following function which isn't injective !

$H(f)(a) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} 1 & f(a)=a\\
0 & \#
\end{array}\right.$

Now let's find an injection from $S_A$ to $2^A$ and from $\mathcal{P}A$ to $S_A$, or another injections !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't find a solution which doesn't use *some* part of the axiom of choice (as shown by Dawson and Howard), but you don't need the entire assumption of the axiom of choice (as shown by Pincus).

> *John W. Dawson, Jr. and Paul E. Howard*, [**Factorials of infinite cardinals**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=434815), *Fund. Math.* **93** (1976), no. 3, 186--195.
>
> *David Pincus*, [**A note on the cardinal factorial**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=528352), *Fund. Math.* **98** (1978), no. 1, 21--24.

It perhaps should be pointed out that assuming the axiom of choice this is a simple calculation since $2^A\leq S_A\leq A^A=2^A$ for all infinite cardinals. (See [Factorial of Infinite Cardinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388785/factorial-of-infinite-cardinal) for details.)

Comment: So which injections are employed to infer that :
$2^A\leq S_A$ and $S_A\leq A^A$ ?

Comment: $S_A$ is an actual subset of $A^A$, the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$; and $2^A$ goes into $S_A$ by defining for each set $B\subseteq A$ a complete derangement which fixes its complement (e.g. partition it into pairs and switch each pair). This, of course, fails to work for singletons but there are only $A$ of them, so we can ignore that in terms of cardinality (i.e. we first prove that $\mathcal P(A)$ and $\{B\subseteq A\mid |B|>1\}$ has the same cardinality, then we inject the second set into $S_A$).