# How does equality $\mathfrak{m}^\mathfrak{m} = 2^\mathfrak{m}$ in $\sf{ZF}$ relate to the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Usually, the equality
$\mathfrak{m}^\mathfrak{m} = 2^\mathfrak{m}$
for infinite cardinal $\mathfrak{m}$ is proved like that:
$$
2^\mathfrak{m} \leqslant \mathfrak{m}^\mathfrak{m} \leqslant (2^\mathfrak{m})^\mathfrak{m} = 2^{\mathfrak{m} \cdot \mathfrak{m}} = 2^\mathfrak{m}
$$
The last step relies much on the axiom of choice, because the fact $\mathfrak{m}\cdot\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}$ does. Moreover, [Tarski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_theorem_about_choice) states that in $\sf{ZF}$ this fact is equivalent to $\sf{AC}$.

Note, by a *cardinal* I mean an equipollence class of an arbitrary set, not necessarily admitting a well-ordering.

That has motivated my question: what can we say about relationship of the initial equality and the axiom of choice in pure $\sf{ZF}$?

---

To avoid question about definition of cardinals without $\sf{AC}$, we may consider the following statement instead:

> For any infinite set $X$ exists a bijection $\; F \, \colon X^X \rightarrow 2^X$

where $X^X$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $X$, $\; 2^X = \mathcal P(X)$ is the power set, and an infinite set is such that cannot be bijectively mapped onto a finite ordinal.

Comment: Tarski's theorem states that $X \times X \approx X$ for every infinite set $X$ implies AC, but $\kappa.\kappa = \kappa$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ can be proven in ZF.

Comment: @nombre, you probably call _cardinal_ thing I call _aleph_, that is cardinality of an _ordinal_. In that sense you are right, but I don't want to debate on the definition of a cardinal.

Comment: Ok. I really don't know whether the second statement implies AC but it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more intense search, I've found the answer from this [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122778/when-does-aa-2a-without-the-axiom-of-choice) and [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807730/factorial-of-infinite-cardinals) questions.

The relation of the subject statement to the axiom of choice seems poor.
So, the subject statement is consistent with $\sf ZF + \neg\sf AC$, as in final remark in [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=528352) paper.
More, its negation also may hold in models of $\sf ZF$ without choice, as in [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=434815) paper!

For reference, permutation models of $\sf ZF$ with atoms (or urelements) used in the above papers are described in book "**The Axiom of Choice**" by Thomas J. Jech.

I hope there may be another interesting contributions to the question.